# Unable To See Screen After AMD Catalyst Driver Install

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, graphics, amd-processor

I have the following setup:

- Z87 Extreme Motherboard.
- Asus HD 7790 Graphics card.
- Asus R9 280x Graphics card.
- Ubuntu 12.04

I have been able to install both the latest beta drivers and the latest stable drivers and they work to a point where I can see both graphics cards after running the following command:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial --adapter=all
```

But when I reboot the screen does not come back to where I can see anything on it.  It just says no signal.  I can remotely `ssh` into the server and run commands from there.  When both graphics cards are connected none of the graphic output ports seem to work.

The on-board graphics card seems to stop working after a reboot and both of the PCI connected do not output anything to screen.  I have tried changing the options for Integrated graphics in the BIOS from on-board to PCI Express (only 2 options available) and various combinations.

When I unplug the graphics cards the system then does not reboot where it will show anything on screen.

It seems when I reboot it switches over to output on one of the cards but no output actually appears on screen.

Adding a graphics card shouldn't be this difficult in Ubuntu.

Has anybody any idea what could be happening or a steer in the right direction?

[EDIT]

As a starting point ... for the two cards I have installed in my system, which drivers should I be installing?  (Note: I have now updated to Ubuntu 13.10 but I see the same issue after rebooting)

Comment: My laptop does the exact same thing, but with a Radeon HD 4250/Radeon HD 5650 card. :) It works great on Open Source drivers, but runs really hot because both cards are "active".

Comment: Mine is a desktop custom build with various parts as described above.  At this stage I have tried installing every variation of beta / stable / old / new driver that I can find.  I have also reinstalled Ubuntu and initially graphics seem to work but after I reboot nothing appears on screen.  BUT on some occasions when I reboot I get an error saying "The system is running in low graphics mode".  When that error appears I can press CTRL+ALT+F1 and login.

I have followed multiple different blog posts on the issue and followed the instructions from the AMD site to install the proprietary driver.